# Ping between pc and wifi router is fluctuating

Tags: wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, ping

So a heaving troubles when playing online with my PS3 by wifi. I have a ADSL Internet, a D-Link DSL-2730B as modem/router (wifi is off) and D-Link DIR-803 wifi router. Both are with default configurations and original firmware.

Sometimes is good, sometimes LAG increases and connection starts to fail. I did speed tests, ping tests, put my kid to play when testing in the moment of failing and my connection seams even above the plan (I pay for 5M but got 7M). It seams an inside trouble, LAN problem. So I begin to test inside. First, of course, I did a physical restart in modem/router and wifi router. I think it tuck a better channel, and start the ping tests. First from my PC to wifi router. But this very first test seams odd already:

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.225 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=2.266 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=8.627 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=130.574 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=1.782 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=169.940 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.748 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=123.464 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=42.733 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=165.570 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.748/64.893/169.940/69.564 ms
```

Sometimes the ping test return only low values, as it should. This one are almost good:

```
PING 192.168.0.1 (192.168.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=2.377 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=8.525 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=3.616 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=2.292 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=4.863 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=2.018 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=1.986 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=3.902 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=77.208 ms
64 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_seq=9 ttl=64 time=208.533 ms

--- 192.168.0.1 ping statistics ---
10 packets transmitted, 10 packets received, 0.0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max/stddev = 1.986/31.532/208.533/62.967 ms
```

You can see that suddenly the time grow up and it seams a response
from a far far away server, not the first node! I can only think about interference. Some people say to upgrade the firmware, I don't know… any ideas?

Comment: WiFi is tricky, most areas are crowded and even though there are 11 channels for 2.4GHz only 3 are really used (1, 6, 11). You can use a WiFi scanner to see which channel is least congested and stick to that, otherwise get a wired connection or try powerline networking as @dylanweber suggested; I've used them, they're great.

Comment: It's now using channel 5. By my wifi scanner, there is only one intermittent signal in channel 6 and the rest is away. But my concern is about other cheap equipments we have in home. Maybe my neighborhood friend has a wifi phone that cause the interference. Unfortunately, the tests takes time, I have to play more using this channel now, but I'm aware that there is alternatives to wifi and wired network.

Answer (score 0):

The PS3 does not have the ability to connect to 5GHz networks, and is stuck communicating over the 2.4GHz band, which can be full of interference. It might be a better solution to look at using [powerline networking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power-line_communication#Home_networking_.28LAN.29) or AC wireless bridges to connect via ethernet to your console.

Powerline network adapters allow you to connect two devices across a home as if an ethernet cable was used, but wall adapters can use the electrical wiring in your house to transmit data from the router to the opposite adapter and into your PS3.

Bridges would act as a wireless client, where you would use an ethernet cable to connect your PS3 to a standalone device for an internet connection.

Comment: This could be the issue, @user6492 should see if this happens to a computer with wired ethernet when the PS3 comes online.

Comment: I don't know why Sony don't use 5GHz connection, even my old 2008 macmini has, and it's used for multimedia and online gaming that it's more demanding on the connection… anyway, I'm researching about power line networking available here (good brand quality and not very expansive), or maybe I'll have to by a 20m ethernet cable. Also, in both cases, I'll plug ps3 direct into modem router to short the way to Internet.

Comment: It's cheaper to not include features that aren't necessary.

Comment: Powerline networking won't work for me, my house has many individual wire power lines, and it only works in the same line. Also, I found advices that other electrical equipment might disturb the signal, so maybe will be good only in a isolated and controlled line. Didn't find any ethernet bridge, as a "virtual cable". Changing wifi channel seams to improve connection quality, maybe there is more configurations we can change to make it better...

Comment: Don't look for "Ethernet bridges," look for wireless bridges. Here is an example product. http://goo.gl/NYWsBH

Comment: There's even another great sounding product I haven't heard of yet: ethernet over coaxial cable https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_over_coax#MoCA

Comment: dylanweber: the tests I presented are by 5GHz wifi from my PC to wifi router, so to buy a bridge, I must make this existing connection better. Coaxial cable ethernet sounds good to me too, I already have coax cables around the house! In the same store, there is one at the same price, I'll investigate the details: http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16833156414&cm_re=ethernet_over_coax-_-33-156-414-_-Product

Comment: Keep in mind that just because you have coaxial outlets in the walls does not mean they're connected to each other from room to room. If you plan to run a single coaxial cable through your house, you might as well just run a regular ethernet cable.